# Page & controller load time!

Tags: apex, visualforce, debugging

To completely capture the page load time, i am using firebug(Firefox) to check the page load time which includes images / CSS / HTML etc.

On the other had, i am using debug logs to check the load time by differentiating start time and end time.

My doubt: How to specifically take or find the UI load time to load only the components.

My page is in customer portal and i am currently working on increasing Page latency!

Comment: Why would you want to increase latency?

Comment: I am sorry if my statement defines a wrong meaning. To be simple, i need to reduce the page loading time., like if its 16 seconds, i need to reduce it to 8 / 10 seconds @ the max.

Comment: see https://www.developerforce.com/guides/Visualforce_in_Practice.pdf Chapter 13 for tips